# Выполнить скрипт после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать скрипт, чтобы он выполнялся только после загрузки страницы, а при обновлении чтобы он не отрабатывал?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#shk_butEmptyCart').click();
   $('#shk_confirmButton').click();
});
```

Comment: Как вариант выделить ваши функции click() в отдельную функцию, которая будет србатывать по флагу, а в качестве флага можно добавить какой-нибудь параметр или хеш в url

Comment: а как с хешем сделать?

Comment: По сути так же как с параметром просто добавить в конце URL # и после нее дописывать уже какой-то флаг, но лучше параметр

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin в URL не совсем хорошее решение какие-то статусы хранить. Всё-таки [URI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) не для этого предназначен.

Comment: @Aslero как Вы представляете себе разницу между "заходит на страницу" и "обновит страницу"? А если он второй раз заходит, тогда что?

Comment: Интересно, есть книга, которая бы учила молодых специалистов достаточно полно условия и требования по задачи писать? Сам бы даже почитал...

Answer (score 2):

А что за скрипт? Запрос на сервер какой-то? Записывать флаг выполнения в через сессия / куки / [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) / [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) / [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) (для больших данных правда). Что душе ближе и к задаче.

К чему привязывать будете я не знаю, потому что не знаю ваш проект: можно к сессии браузера, то есть при первом посещении, или по id пользователя прошедшего аутентификацию.

**Например через localStorage:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var runScript = localStorage.getItem("run-script");

            if (runScript === null && runScript !== "true") {
                alert("Первый запуск скрипта");

                localStorage.setItem("run-script", "true")
            } else {
                alert("Скрипт уже был запущен");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66065/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-bragin-----).